# In Bash script trying to pass local variable to SSH and then execute the other commands

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, ssh

```
#!/bin/bash

count2=1
declare -a input
input=( "$@" )

echo " "
echo " Hostname passed by user is " ${input[0]}
HOST="${input[0]}"

sshpass -p '<pass>' ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@$HOST /bin/bash  << ENDSSH

echo " Connected "
echo $count2
echo $input
pwd
echo $count2: ${input[$count2]}
nic=${input[$count2]}
echo $nic
echo $(ethtool "${nic}" |& grep 'Link' | awk '{print $3}')

ENDSSH
```

So Actually want to pass variable `'count2'` and `'input'` to remote SSH and execute.
But unfortunately it is not getting passed. It is not echoing anything after SSH.
Need help in this.!!
I have sshpass installed in sever.

code output:

```
[user@l07 ~]$ ./check.sh <hostname> eno6

 Hostname passed by user is  <hostname>
 Connected
```

After SSH it only echos "Connected". I'm not sure why `$count2` and `$input` is not echoing.
I tired with backlash '`\$count2'` but that is also not working. All possible combination tried even with quote and unquote of `ENDSSH`. Pls help

Any help will be really appreciated!!

Comment: Please paste your script first at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: Yes I tired and fixed issue like double quotes and ```\``` backlash before echo $input to echo \$input and similar for echo \$nic. But same issue still. !!

Comment: @Pranjul : You don't **pass** any variables to the remote side, but you **interpolate** them in your here-document, just before invoking `sshpass`.

Comment: @user1934428: Could you pls explain this more , I didn't understood  what you are trying to say may be because I'm new to bash script. Any solution which can  help to solve this problem.

Comment: "passing a variable" means that the remote side has a variable of the same name, with the same value, when it starts running. Right? You don't do anything in your code, which would achieve this (or at least I don't see it). For ssh, what has to be done is described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/48783/how-can-i-pass-an-environment-variable-through-an-ssh-command#702751).

Comment: @user1934428: Actually I want to pass user input which contain hostname and args. And this args I want to pass to SSH and execute them remotely. Command to run script is ```./check.sh <hostname> eno6```. So ```eno6``` is user input which needs to be executed remotely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

count2=1
declare -a input
input=( "$@" )

echo " Hostname passed by user is " "${input[0]}"
HOST="${input[0]}"

while [ $# -gt $count2 ]
do

    sed -i 's/VALUE/'"${input[$count2]}"'/g' ./check.sh 

sshpass -p '<pass>' scp ./check.sh user@"$HOST":/home/user/check.sh
sshpass -p '<pass>' ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@"$HOST" "sh /home/user/check.sh && rm -rf /home/user/check.sh"
 
sed -i 's/'"${input[$count2]}"'/VALUE/g' ./check.sh
((count2++))

done
```

Found the another solution of this issue: It is working for me now !!!!

I wrote my entire logic which needs to be executed remotely in `check.sh` file and now replacing or storing the user input into this `check.sh` file and copying this file into remote server via scp and executing it over remotely and after successful execution removing this file from remote server and after ssh , again changing the user input to it's original value in local server using `sed` command.

Made this as dynamic script to work for multiple servers.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add escapes(`\`) here:

```
...
echo \$nic
...
echo \$(ethtool "\${nic}" |& grep 'Link' | awk '{print \$3}')
...
```

But why echoing this? Try it without `echo`

```
...
ethtool "\${nic}" |& grep -i 'Link' | awk '{print \$3}'
...
```

Comment: `echo \$(ethtool "\${nic}" |& grep 'Link' | awk '{print \$3}') `  this echo is not working, not showing any output.

Comment: Try it like this `... |& grep -i 'Link' | ...`

Comment: And do you need `echo` here? Just run `ethtool ... |& ... | ...`

Comment: `echo \$(ethtool "\${nic}" |& grep -i 'Link' | awk '{print \$3}')` passing like this shows no output but when I'm passing like this without ``\`` `echo $(ethtool "\${nic}" |& grep 'Link' | awk '{print \$3}')` then output shows `Cannot get link status: No such device` , but in actually device is there and it's Link-Detected is Yes. Don't know why it is behaving so strange !!

Comment: Without this `\\` you get output from your local host.

Comment: `echo` is required because I want to check the status of 'Link'  whether it is up or down and based on that will perform some `if and else` condition , so echo will make sure whether this command has ran successfully and giving the desired output or not. I can assign this command to some variable but will not come to know that command has given the correct output or no. Expected output of command is `yes` or `down`..

Answer (score 0):

You basically want to supply to your remote bash a HERE-document to be executed. This is tricky, since you need to "compose" the full text of this document before you can supply it to ssh. I would therefore separate the task into two parts:

1. Creating the HERE-document
2. Running it on ssh

This makes it easy for debugging to output the document between steps 1 and 2 and to visually inspect its contents for correctness. Don't forget that once this code runs on the remote host, it can't access any of your variables anymore, unless you have "promoted" them to the remote side using the means provided by ssh.

Hence you could start like this:

```
# Create the parameters you want to use
nic=${input[$count2]}

# Create a variable holding the content of the remote script,
# which interpolates your parameters
read -r -d '' remote_script << ENDSSH
echo "Connected to host \$(hostname)"
echo "Running bash version: \$BASH_VERSION"
....
ethtool "$nic" |& grep Link | awk '{ print $3 }'
ENDSSH

# Print your script for verification
echo "$remote_script"

# Submit it to the host
sshpass -p '<pass>' ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no "user@$HOST" /bin/bash <<<"$remote_script"
```

Comment: Really Appreciate your effort @user1934428:   `Connected to host
Running bash version: 4.2.46(2)-release
eno6
Cannot get link status: No such device
`  this command in script throws mentioned error `echo $(ethtool "$nic" |& grep -i 'Link' | awk '{print $3}')` but anyway in remote server when I'm running this command in cli then output comes as `Yes`. `grep` with `-i` in command gives such output `Cannot get link status: No such device`  and only `grep` in command give no output. Not sure what i'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Did you verify the content of the variable `nic`? Perhaps it has an incorrect value. What does the `echo "$remote_script"` show?